# IPC Queues:- Receiving wrong data

Tags: c, posix, ipc, message-queue, system-calls

My program is receiving wrong data on `msgrcv` function if flag is set to 0, however, if i set flag to 1 for specific data then `msgrcv` function is keep waiting. I defined send and receive function in common file and calling it from sender and receiver file. I checked debug data and it was sent properly but on receiving end if flag set to 0 means receive first packet then i am getting wrong data. If set flag to 1 which means specific message type data `msgrcv` function ended in waiting state. Please help.
/*CommonMsgQueue.c*/

```
    int InitializeMsgQueue(char *keypath)
    {
       key_t key;
       int msgid;
       key = ftok(keypath,'B');
       if (key == -1 )
       {
          perror("Failed to generate key ");
          exit(0);
       }
       msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );
       if ( msgid == -1 )
       {
          perror("Failed to get msgid");
          exit(0);
       }
       return msgid;
    }
    int SendMsg(key_t msgqid ,StMesgQ *MsgData , int msglength)
    {
        int iRetVal =0;
        iRetVal = msgsnd(msgqid,&MsgData,sizeof(StMesgQ),IPC_NOWAIT);
        if ( iRetVal == -1 )
        {
           perror("Failed to send message");
        }
        return iRetVal;
    }
    int RcvMsg(key_t msgqid, StMesgQ *MsgData , int msglength)
    {
       int iRetVal =0;
       iRetVal = msgrcv(msgqid,&MsgData,msglength,0,0);
       if (iRetVal == -1 )
       {
          perror("Failed to receive message ");
          exit(0);
       }
       
       return iRetVal;
    
    }
   /*Sender.c*/
   msgqid = InitializeMsgQueue("/home/nprabhat/Nitesh/Nitesh_FrameWork/Key/ClientQueue");
   CommonSHMData = (struct CommonSHM*)ShmData;
   StMesgQ obj;
   while (1)
   {
       
       printf("Sender:-- Enter the value For iIndex\n");
       scanf("%d",&value);
       CommonSHMData->iIndex = value;
       CommonSHMData->iIndex2 = value;
       DataPktToSend = (char*)CommonSHMData;
     memcpy(&obj.buf,&DataPktToSend,strlen(DataPktToSend));
       obj.iMsgType = 1;
       SendMsg(msgqid,&obj,sizeof(StMesgQ));
    }
  /*Reciever.c*/
  RcvMsg(msgqid,&MsgData,sizeof(StMesgQ));
  CommonSHMData_Recv = (struct CommonSHM*)MsgData.buf;
  printf("Data Received from queue is %d",CommonSHMData_Recv->iIndex);
```

Comment: It seems your code is wrong. Where is the close bracket of while loop? And what is the name of your flag in the code?

Comment: i didn't posted my full code . i missed the close braces of "while loop" while posting the code. Fourth argument of msgrcv function indicates flag . We can set it 0,-1 or 1 according to our need.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Given `int RcvMsg(key_t msgqid, StMesgQ *MsgData , int msglength)`, the code `msgrcv(msgqid,&MsgData,msglength,0,0);` is putting the message contents in the location of the `MsgData` ***pointer***.

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
   iRetVal = msgrcv( msgqid, &MsgData, msglength, 0, 0 );
   
   if (iRetVal == -1 )
   {
      perror("Failed to receive message ");
      exit(0);
   }
   
   memcpy(&MsgData,&RcvMsgData,sizeof(StMesgQ));
```

the function: `memcpy()` copies from right to left.

Here is the syntax:

```
void *memcpy(void *destination, const void *source, size_t n);
```

So the call to `memcpy()` is overlaying the data placed in `MsgData` by the call to `msgrcv()` with whatever trash happens to be in `RcvMsgData`

Comment: Also, `MsgData` is a **pointer** to `StMesgQ`, so the `msgrcv()` call is overwriting the pointer itself with the message contents - and probably a lot more.